# Postgresql archived WALs

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm working with PostgreSQl version 9.6. I have set the postgresql.conf in this way:

```
# - Archiving -

archive_mode = on
            # (change requires restart)
archive_command = 'rsync --delete-after -a %p /data2/postgresBKP/%f'
```

The archive folder /data2/postgresBKP/ now is very big (395G). Can I safely revove the old WAL files from the archive folder /data2/postgresBKP/?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all archived WAL segments that are no longer needed.

In particular, don't delete any WAL archives that are needed to restore the oldest base backup you want to be able to restore.

PostgreSQL does not take care of archived WAL segments, you have to do that yourself. A simple way would be a scheduled job that deletes all files older than a certain age.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, if I have correctly understood, the archived WAL files are not used by PostgreSQL, they can be used by me to restore an older version of the DB. So if I know that I don't want to restore backup of 2019, I can safely delete all the 2019 archived files, right?

Comment: That's right. You should schedule a regular removal job.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend taking backups periodically and clearing up old Wal logs.
For now if you can stop the server then stop it, Take a backup first and restart it. Then you can safely remove old wal logs.
You can use pg_basebackup tool and pg_archivecleanup to achieve it.